# homebrew update irritating error message

Tags: git, postgresql, homebrew

When I do ...

```
brew update
```

I keep getting this error message ...

```
From https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
25c0495..af1d9f1  master     -> origin/master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: 
       Library/Formula/postgresql.rb
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

I wanted to find the file, and checkout the latest version but I can't even find the folder 'Formula'. Hmm.. So I uninstall postgresql and tried 'brew update' again but encounter same error.

Appreciate if anyone can help me out ?

Comment: Please don't put the answer inside the question. Post it as a answer and then accept it to mark this question as "answered".

Comment: I wish I could do it now ...

"Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking."

Comment: @meagar: If you remove the answer from the question, at least post it as an answer yourself! (See answer.)

Comment: @Erwin No. If he wants to answer it, he can do it correctly.

Comment: @meagar: That would be the optimum, but John is new and obviously doesn't know the customs. Pooria mostly did the right thing, posting the answer as community wiki. It helps the reader. I only transferred his comment form the answer to an actual comment.

Comment: Why would someone give me de-merit for this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```bsh
cd `brew --repository`
git reset --hard HEAD
brew update
```

Sometimes the above doesn't work. In that case, do

```bsh
cd `brew --repository`
git reset --hard origin/master
brew update
```

Comment: `@`-comments only notify the addressee in comments, not in answers. I made the comment into an actual comment under the question which now reaches meagar.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks. And I converted my answer to 'community wiki'.

Comment: The second one worked for me.

Comment: you may want to save these changes, in that case `git stash` or `git checkout -b my_custom_postgresql_formula && git commit -am"my modifications"`